# How to deal with HTTPError 403 when using OAuth2 authentication with Python (V. 3.8.1)?

Tags: python, oauth-2.0, http-error, google-search-console

When trying to query the Google Search Console for certain metrics (not pictured) using the Google search Console API, specifically OAuth 2.0, I am getting a HTTPError 403: "returned "User does not have sufficient permission for site 'XXXXXXXX.com'. See also: [https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/2451999."](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/2451999.%22). Details: "[{'message': "User does not have sufficient permission for site 'https://www.xxxxxx.com'. See also: https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/2451999.", 'domain': 'global', 'reason': 'forbidden'}]">" (replaced site URL with x's)

I have also gotten a 403 error that says I do not have a Google Analytics account on some other attempts.

Below is the code to authorize the access:

```
def get_domain_name(start_url):
    domain_name = '{uri.netloc}'.format(uri=urlparse(start_url))  # Get Domain Name To Name Project
    domain_name = domain_name.replace('.','_')
    return domain_name
 
 
def create_project(directory):
    if not os.path.exists(directory):
        print('Create project: '+ directory)
        os.makedirs(directory)


def authorize_creds(creds):
    # Variable parameter that controls the set of resources that the access token permits.
    SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/webmasters.readonly']
 
    # Path to client_secrets.json file
    CLIENT_SECRETS_PATH = creds
 
    # Create a parser to be able to open browser for Authorization
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
        formatter_class=argparse.RawDescriptionHelpFormatter,
        parents=[tools.argparser])
    flags = parser.parse_args([])
 
    flow = client.flow_from_clientsecrets(
        CLIENT_SECRETS_PATH, scope = SCOPES,
        message = tools.message_if_missing(CLIENT_SECRETS_PATH))
 
    # Prepare credentials and authorize HTTP
    # If they exist, get them from the storage object
    # credentials will get written back to a file.
    storage = file.Storage('authorizedcreds.dat')
    credentials = storage.get()
 
    # If authenticated credentials don't exist, open Browser to authenticate
    if credentials is None or credentials.invalid:
        credentials = tools.run_flow(flow, storage, flags)
    http = credentials.authorize(http=httplib2.Http())
    webmasters_service = build('webmasters', 'v3', http=http)
    return webmasters_service
```

Comment: Are you saying you don't believe the error?  It seems to be recognizing your user as valid, but says that you don't have the right to access that site.  Are you sure that you do?

Comment: I have gone into permissions in the search console as well as the cloud platform and added the company website that I am trying to query. I do believe that error but I gave permissions to the best of my knowledge as I was given admin access to the account. I have also looked at other stack overflow pages of the same error but they don't help.